# ComponentDidMount() life cycle

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I am a react beginner and was looking at the "ComponentDidMount" life cycle. What I saw is that ComponentDidMount is called once the page is mounted in the browser. Absolutely fine.
But what amazed me is that We can set a subscription or do event Listener in that part too. Then how are we subscribing and where is it subscribing in react? Like how does it work in react?

Comment: I don't think you need to unsubscribe, that is something handled by the library, basically when react mounts you component it also calls the function you associated with `ComponentDidMount`.

Anyway I wanted to tell you that this way to listen to life cycle events is being substituted by hooks, have you looked into those?

Comment: Hi @DarioPiotrowicz, yes I know hooks is a great way to solve the problem of componentDidMount using useEffect Hooks API but since I was learning react so I looked through it, and I think we need to unsubscribe that too because otherwise if the component gets detached, then also it will be working which can cause memory leaks. But I think you are correct on the part that the react handles the background of the PubSub (Publisher-Subscriber) pattern of Listeners.

Comment: You know, I am an Angular developer and I just learned React on the side. Have you ever used Angular? In angular there are subscription which you need to look for and those explicit subscriptions are know to be a often cause memory leaks when you destroy a component. That being said, those aren't related to life cycle hooks, like cylce  hooks are handled by the framework and you just tell it what extra code you want it to execute.

Comment: I just wanted to mention Angular just because it also has life cycle hooks but you can put any time of code you want and there will not be memory leaks (there may be other issues lol, but that's unrelated here of course). But if you actively listen/subscribe to something, then it is necessary to unsubscribe. That holds in Angular and I am sure it does so in React :)

Comment: lol, would you mind if I put my comments as an answer? may be worth doing so at this point :P

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz, first of all, thank you for taking your time and answering this. and yes you can put your answer in the comment. 
and yes I got it what are you trying to say by relating it with angular. I have also done work in angular too but there we write these logical codes in the service files. I hope you know about this. and from there we manage these states. But in react I think the react is in background handling all this.

Comment: Yes of course :), I was keeping services out since we were talking about components and life cycle hooks :) . I will search some docs online and will put an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that React already implements those methods for each and every component, they are simply empty by default and you are simply given the change to override them with your own methods (as you can briefly see in the introductory section of the [official doc on components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)).

Basically as you can imagine React does run various instructions to take your components, inject them in the page, update their view, remove them, etc... when it does so, naturally it knows in what part of the life cycle the component is in, so for react is extremely simple to add the execution of your code to what it is already doing.

So you don't need to care who or how is calling your method/code as that is something that react is already fully set up to take care of.

That being said, if you create timers, subscribe to promises, observables or anything of such asynchronous nature, you may need to clean up after those (React can't do that for you as it does not know about those subscription), and that can be done in the `componentWillUnmount()` life cycle method which gets run before the component unmounts from the page.
(I hope you checked out this [diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/), it is really well made)

That being said, I think it is important to keep in mind that moving forward React is moving away from class based components and suggest the use of functional components with the use of [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) instead of class components with life cycle methods.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation. and this clears my doubts.

Comment: My pleasure, I am so glad you could find it useful :)